# Does this Jacobi method program works?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I tried to made a python function that simulates Jacobi linear system solving for Ax=b, for a certain tolerance of error in aproximation and a maximum limit of iterations.
My code is the following

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as nla


def jacobi_iterative(A, b, tolerance, max_it):  # a_ii!= 0 for all i
    n = A.shape[0]
    x = np.zeros(np.shape(b))
    err = 1.0
    it_num = 0
    while it_num < max_it:
        for i in range(n):
            x_k = x.copy()
            temp_i_row = A[i, :].copy()
            temp_i_row[i] = 0.0
            x_k[i] = (-1) * (1 / A[i][i]) * (np.dot(temp_i_row, x_k) + b[i])
        err = nla.norm(x_k - x, np.inf) / nla.norm(x_k, np.inf)
        if err < tolerance:
            x = x_k
            it_num += 1
            break
        else:
            x = x_k
            it_num += 1
    return x, err, it_num
```

and i have this test case

```
A_1 = np.array([[3.0, -1.0, 1.0], [3.0, 6.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0, 7.0]])
b_1 = np.array([1, 0, 5])
x_1 = jacobi_iterative(A_1, b_1, 1e-5, 1000)
```

which gives me the next result

```
x_1 == (array([ 0.03508655,  0.26315766, -0.84210466]), 4.230199685061763e-06, 10)
```

but I'm not sure if my code works properly, is there an in-built function of the jacobi method that could give the same data to compare it?

Comment: Create some test data, call it and compare the results to what you know the answer should be. If you don't understand why the results don't match your expectations, you can share your results and ask a question about that - you can't expect people here to do your work for you though.

Comment: @Grismar it's not like that, i do have my test case, let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified your algorithm, but it looks reasonable at a glance.
Although since you are using numpy anyway, you could probably exploit the library further to make your algorithm cleaner.

If you haven't already done so, the first easy verification test you can do is to try if your solved x actually fits Ax=b.
To do this you can use:

```
np.dot(A,x)
```

Edit I take the rest of my previous answer back.
The x_1 result that you posted looks reasonable ( Except for that the signs looks inverted) It should be [ -0.03508655,  -0.26315766, 0.84210466].

```
  np.dot(A, [ 0.03508655,  0.26315766, -0.84210466]) 

  out: array([1.00000267e+00, 3.71000000e-06, 4.99999999e+00])
```

Which is fairly close.
However the bigger problem, is that the code that you posted , when running on my machine doesn't result in anything close you the x_1 that you posted.

You shouldn't have any major problem finding an open reference implementation of jacobi for python, e.g. [Jacobi Method in Python and NumPy](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Jacobi-Method-in-Python-and-NumPy/) so that you can compare your results to the reference.